# How to Verify an Email Address in Python Using smtplib and MX record

Tags: python, smtplib

I am using this code to validate email. It runs at the first few validation, but soon it shows an error OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable when I am running it frequently. Please help! Thanks

```
def validate_email(email):
  import dns.resolver
  import socket
  import smtplib
  splitAddress = email.split('@')
  domain = str(splitAddress[1])
  records = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
  mxRecord = records[0].exchange
  mxRecord = str(mxRecord)
  host = socket.gethostname()
  server = smtplib.SMTP()
  server.set_debuglevel(0)
  server.connect(mxRecord)
  server.helo(host)
  server.mail('me@domain.com')
  code, message = server.rcpt(str(email))
  server.quit()
  time.sleep(1)
  return code
```

Comment: If you are trying to see is valid as in it is proper like ```www.example@domain.com``` then regular expression is your friend. link to the python doc - https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Hi Joshua, in my case, I do not only need regular expression, but also the code above to validate the validity of the email.

Comment: so what you are doing is verifying the email not validating it

Comment: okay, so do you know what's wrong with my code above? hmm.

Comment: can anyone help please?